# Error message while using Test::MockObject->fake_module

Tags: perl, testing, mocking

I have inherited a perl project that I am having a problem testing. There are existing tests, and one of them uses the Test::MockObject->fake_module function. This test passes now. However, if I add a use (or use_ok) for an additional testing module (which also works ok in different tests), I am getting the following:

> No mocked subs for loaded module 'IO::File'

In the test in question we have this:

```
my $io_file_mock = Test::MockObject->new();
$io_file_mock->set_isa('IO::File', 'IO::Handle');
$io_file_mock->set_true('flush', 'print');
$io_file_mock->fake_module('IO::File');
$io_file_mock->fake_new('IO::File');
```

I see in the documentation for MockObject->fake_module that this is written:

> If you use fake_module() to mock a module that already exists in memory -- one you've loaded elsewhere perhaps, but do not pass any subroutines to mock, this method will throw an exception. This is because if you call the constructor later on, you probably won't get a mock object back and you'll be confused.

Not sure I understand this message and how I can make my test work.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by putting the above code in a separate BEGIN block before the BEGIN block that calls my use_ok calls. Is there any problem with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the comments:

> I was able to solve my problem by putting the above code in a separate BEGIN block before the BEGIN block that calls my use_ok calls. Is there any problem with that? - Mark

A [`BEGIN`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/BEGIN.html) code block is executed as soon as possible, that is, the moment it is completely defined, even before the rest of the containing file (or string) is parsed.

If the `use_ok` method that was failing is in a `BEGIN` block and it depended other variables, then those dependent variables would need to be initialized in a `BEGIN` block as well or they would be temporarily `undef` when `use_ok` was called.

For more information read: [BEGIN, UNITCHECK, CHECK, INIT and END](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END)